# extensional vs intensional view of set equality applied to the uniqueness of the empty set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

By definition of set equality, two sets are equal are equal precisely when they contain the same elements. The extensional view would mean that if two sets A and B have the same elements, then A and B are in fact two different labels for the same underlying set. Now, apply that view to empty sets. If you take any two sets that are empty, they must be equal to one another, since they contain the same elements(namely, no elements at all.). This implies there is only one empty set.

Under the intentional view of set equality, two sets A and B could have the same elements and yet be two different sets all together. This would imply that there could be empty sets A and B, with the same elements(namely, no elements). Conclusion, There is no unique empty set.

Please help me understand where my understanding is flawed. Everywhere on StackExchange and elsewhere, I read that the empty set is unique. Yet I am struggling to see how given the 'intensional view' of set equality.

Comment: The “extensional view”, as you call it, is perhaps the most basic axiom governing how sets work. It is almost universally accepted as an axiom among working mathematicians.